# Ubuntu 17.10 - configure mirroring or disable main laptop screen without access to the UI

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop whose screen is broken. The only way I can see what's going on is by plugging an external monitor.

The problem is that after the upgrade, plugging the external screen extends the desktop, but I can't see what's going on the main screen. So impossible to log-in, and configure the displays to only use the external monitor.

Is there any way I can, from the command-line, force the UI to either exactly mirror the two screens, or disable the main laptop screen?

Thanks,
Sami

Comment: Since Ubuntu 17.10 defaults with Wayland, I don't have an answer for Wayland.  However, if you're using X.Org you can do it with `xrandr` with `--same-as` switch like `xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --same-as DVI-I-2` where you would replace the `DVI-I-` with your own ports that are connected.

Comment: Not really a generic solution, but as far as my laptop is concerned, if I boot Ubuntu with the lid closed, the laptop screen is not recognized as a screen, which means that everything appears on the external display. 

It solves my issue, but I'm unsure whether it's applicable to other brands.

Answer (score 0):

My display configuration (xfce) has option "Mirror displays" disabled.

After a lengthy search process i had success when I added --same-as ...
to a bash-file:

/usr/bin/xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1680x1050 --rate 60 --primary
/usr/bin/xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1680x1050 **--same-as eDP-1**

Result: "Mirror displays" still disabled, **but displays are in fact mirrored**